# Can a continuous function take finite and infinite values?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $X$ be a convex subspace of $\mathbb R^n$.
Can a function $f:X\mapsto \mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ be continuous when there are $x_1,x_2\in X$ such that $f(x_1)=\infty$ and  $f(x_2)<\infty$?

My intuition is that that's not possible, here is my reasoning:
We take a continuous path $(x_t)_{1\leq t\leq 2}$ from $x_1$ to $x_2$.
Then there has to be an $x_s$ such that $f(x_s)=\infty$, but $f(x_{s+\epsilon})<\infty, \forall\epsilon>0$.

Is my intuition right or am I missing something?

Comment: You can define a topology on $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ so $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty\}$ is continuous.  See the one- and two-point compactifications of $\mathbb{R}$, for example.

Comment: Yes, but that requires to define a different metric. Under the standard euclidian metric, f cannot be continuous.

Comment: @hyprfrco What is "the standard Euclidean metric" on $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$?

Comment: You need a topology on $\mathbb{R} \cup \{ \infty \}$ in order to talk about continuous. There is a standard one in which a function such as $x \mapsto {1 \over x}$ is continuous in $[0,1]$ (defining the value at $x=0$ to be $\infty$, of course).

Comment: This is not clear on any of the given question which is the topology on which to apply the continuity. Just "adding" an element to $\mathbb{R}$ is not enough. If so, we have properly to interpret $|x-x_0|<\delta$ and $|f(x)-f(x_0|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Only the artificial inclusion of a $\infty$ symbol does not mean anything as is. The introduction of the metric induced by the topology is the remarkable fact.

Comment: @copper.hat That seems pretty close to what I was looking for. How does this topology look?

Comment: @MilliOnaire: Take the usual open sets in the reals and add a local base for $\infty$ by adding sets of the form  $(a,\infty) \cup \{\infty\}$ to the topology. Another way would be to use a metric of the form $d(x,y) = |\arctan x - \arctan y|$ and define $d(x,\infty)=|\arctan x -{\pi \over 2}|$, etc. Remember that this is a topology on the range.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's define a topology on $\mathbb R\cup \{\infty\}$, where an open set of $\mathbb R\cup \{\infty\}$ will be:

- an open set of $\mathbb R$
- the set of the form $(\mathbb R\setminus K)\cup\{\infty\}$ where $K$ is a compact of $\mathbb R$.

For this topology, the application

$$x\mapsto \frac 1{x^2}$$ will be continuous on $\mathbb R$, and will satisfy your condition.

*Remark: and application $\varphi$ is continuous if, and only if, for all open subset $\Omega$, $\varphi^{-1}(\Omega)$ is open.*

Comment: An alternative topology would be the order topology, generated by all sets $\{x | a < x\}$ and $\{x | x < b\}$. This would allow you to differentiate between $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. Functions like $1/x$ (that go to positive and minus infinity simultaneously) would be discontinuous in the order topology, but would be continuous in yours.

Comment: In this context by $x\mapsto \frac{1}{x^2}$ you mean that the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$ is continuous, right? How do you define $f(0)$ in this case? Would be grateful it you clarify your answer a bit, please!

Comment: @ZFR We define $f(0)=\infty$

Answer (score 0):

May be you need $\frac{1}{\vert x \vert}$

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/823959)

Comment: It is near answer, but yes, you are right. Topology is from Riemann sphere?